# Google Maps is not open on wordpress post page of themes

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, javascript-objects

I have a wordpress theme for classified or directory listing, which having the error about maps while I am going to open any post, the maps is not coming on the post.  for http://www.classifybazaar.com/archives/51 plz check and it return a suitable answer.

Comment: Please post your error and your code attempts, and refine your question title...Its not very clear

Comment: After briefly inspecting your website with Chrome's JavaScript Console, it turns out I've noticed your website is missing the Google API Key. Make sure you're checking the right documentation for your WordPress theme here: https://designinvento.ticksy.com/article/7995/

Comment: did you added google map api?

Answer (score 0):

From the given link:

[image]

You have 2 Warnings and 1 error from the Gmaps API.

To solve them, you only have to add an API key.
If this is not done already, you need to register to an API key according to the service you are using:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key

Then simply add the key parameter to your request like this:

```
&key=[YOURAPIKEY]
```

Please bare in mind, if you are using some theme with Gmaps shortcode you will probably have to insert your api key within the theme options in your admin instance.

Comment: Thanks but where I will find the Please bare in mind, if you are using some theme with Gmaps shortcode you will probably have to insert your api key within the theme options in your admin instance.

Comment: It depends on the theme you are using. Go to Wordpress Admin, and search for something called theme Options. Sometimes this is also called by the name of the theme. It really depends. Then you have to search for the place to insert Google Maps API. What is the name of theme you are using?